# PostgreSQL NOT IN Multiple Wildcards

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.6

Any idea why the following works:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.Survey SURV
WHERE (SURV.Title ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%Empl%', '%Cont%', '%Staff%']))
```

But this does not:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.Survey SURV
WHERE (SURV.Title NOT ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%Empl%', '%Cont%', '%Staff%']))
```

I am not receiving an error, however, the first query appears to return all proper results, while the second query does not appear to be removing any records from my result set.

Please note:  SURV.Title does not have any `NULL` values in the column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a mistake in your boolean logic. Consider, e.g., the string `abcEmplxyz`. It **is**  `ILIKE '%Empl%'`, but **is not** `ILIKE '%Cont%'`, so it would be returned. When you negate a boolean condition like that, you need to substitute the `any` with `all`:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.Survey SURV
WHERE (SURV.Title NOT ILIKE ALL (ARRAY['%Empl%', '%Cont%', '%Staff%']))
-- Here --------------------^
```

Comment: or `WHERE NOT (SURV.Title ILIKE ANY (ARRAY['%Empl%', '%Cont%', '%Staff%']))`

Comment: Thanks - this does what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a regular expression?

```
WHERE NOT LOWER(SURV.Title) ~ 'empl|cont|staff'
```